# Converting from mod_python to mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, mod-python

My website is written in Python and currently runs under mod_python with Apache. Lately I've had to put in a few ugly hacks that make me think it might be worth converting the site to mod_wsgi. But I've gotten used to using some of mod_python's utility classes, especially `FieldStorage` and `Session` (and sometimes `Cookie`), and from a scan of [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), I don't see any equivalents to these. (Not surprising, because I understand that those kinds of utilities don't belong in the WSGI spec)

Question is, are there "standard" (i.e. commonly accepted) replacements for these mod_python utility classes that I can use in WSGI, or could I/should I write my own?

(FYI: currently using Python 2.5)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/).  You may have to do some rewriting.  You will probably be pleased with the results of imposing the WSGI world-view on your application.

Comment: Rolled my own.  Now thinking I should remove my own out and replace it with Werkzeug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FieldStorage in 'cgi' module and the 'Cookie' module. There is no equivalent to Session in Python standard libraries. For WSGI applications you can use [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/) for sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at 
[whiff](http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W.intro) -- it provides built in functionality for manipulating field data
and sessions among others to wsgi based applications.